# Scoping issue with before in Mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js, chromeless

I'm facing an issue regarding test setup and cleanup in `before` and `after` methods in `Mocha` testing.

I'm using [Chromeless](https://github.com/graphcool/chromeless) for e2e testing. For the easier implementation I moved my chrome launcher to a separate file (say `my-chrome-launcher.js`) by exporting an `async` function:

```
var chromeLauncher = require('chrome-launcher');

module.exports = {
    launchChrome: async function(headless) {
        try {
            var flags = ['--disable-gpu'];

            if (headless) {
                flags = ['--headless', '--disable-gpu'];
            }

            let chrome = await chromeLauncher.launch({
                port: 9222,
                chromeFlags: flags
            });

            console.log(`Chrome debugging running on port ${chrome.port} with pid ${chrome.pid}`);
            return chrome;
        } catch (ex) {
            console.error(ex.messsage);
        }
    }
}
```

**simple.js**

```
const {
    Chromeless
} = require('Chromeless')
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var assert = require('assert');
const myChromeLauncher = require('./my-chrome-launcher.js');

describe('app', function() {

    describe('Top Results', function() {

        it('should return top results', async() => {
            chrome = await myChromeLauncher.launchChrome(true);
            chromeless = new Chromeless();

            const links = await chromeless
                .goto('https://www.google.com')
                .type('chromeless', 'input[name="q"]')
                .press(13)
                .wait('#resultStats')
                .evaluate(() => {
                    // this will be executed in headless chrome
                    const links = [].map.call(
                        document.querySelectorAll('.g h3 a'),
                        a => ({ title: a.innerText, href: a.href })
                    )
                    return links;
                });
            // Assert
            assert.equal(links.length, 11);

            await chromeless.end();

            chrome.kill().catch(e => console.error(e));
        });
    });

});
```

The above test works well but when I want to use `before`, `beforeEach`, `after` or `afterEach` methods to share setup code like below I get an error:

```
 describe('app', function() {

     describe('Top Results', function() {
         var chrome;
         var chromeless;

         before(function() {
             chrome = await myChromeLauncher.launchChrome(true);
             chromeless = new Chromeless();
         });

 ....

         after(function() {
             await chromeless.end();
             chrome.kill().catch(e => console.error(e));
         });

});

});
```

**Error:**

```
chrome = await myChromeLauncher.launchChrome(true);
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `before` handler also needs to be `async` i.e.

```
before(async function() {
   chrome = await myChromeLauncher.launchChrome(true);
   chromeless = new Chromeless();
});
```

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

> The await operator is used to wait for a Promise. It can only be used inside an async function.